# Correlation between Migraine Events and Barometric Pressure

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, continuous-data, recurrent-events

I have historic air pressure line graphs and I have superimposed the dates on which I have suffered migraine attacks. I can see that my migraines are most likely to occur around 3 days after a sharp drop in pressure of more than 15 mBar over 3 days and sometimes about 1 day after a very large rise in pressure if it is more than about 30mBar over 3 days.

What is the best statistical test to apply to this to prove there is a connection?

I can see that I may have to change the barometric values into rates of change over time. I may also have to factor in that changes while pressure is low may be more likely to trigger attacks tban changes while it is high.

Also I may have to filter the fluctuations for frequency... Maybe I need to take say a 3 day running average from the barometer graph to put into the statisical test, or possibly start taking readings more often than once a day.

I am hoping to be able to reliably predict my migraines and then hopefully prevent them by taking medication only at the 'right time' instead of taking them more often than I need to.

Comment: If you search the medical literature for air pollution and migraine you can find articles which use mdoels with a variety of lags. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0160412018312704?via%3Dihub is an example and is not behind a paywall. You might be able to import some of those ideas into your case. I know you are interested in pressure rather than pollution but that should not matter.

Comment: Please be aware there does not exist a valid statistical test that uses the same data you have employed to construct your hypothesis.  Thus, any test that might be recommended here has to be applied to *future* values.  That can still be problematic because the subject is not blinded to the experiment!  Regardless, it is important that you specify your hypothesis as clearly as possible: the many "maybes" and "hopes" in this question leave us wondering what that hypothesis might be.

Answer (score 0):

It’ll be hard to prove this, but kudos to you for being creative!!

Not sure how much data you have and I’m not confident there is a simple test for this but you can definitely make progress here.

What we want to know are two statistics:

Sensitivity: what fraction of your migraines occur after a pressure change of X

Specificity: What fraction of pressure changes precede a migraine.

If both statistics are high then you may be onto something.

As for statistical tests — there are bootstrapping and resampling approaches one could use but they require a computer — no nice formulas.